# how do i only let my program continue if the hexadecimal is only using 1-9 and a-f?

Tags: python

## this code is used to convert hexadecimal to (decimal)

i am not understanding how to only allow the program to continue if the the letters are up to f

```
def option6():
    print("\n")
    print("----------------HEXADECIMAL-DENARY-----------------")
    #converts the entered hexadecimal (in base 16) into a integer using the int function
    hexa = input("Please Enter a Hexadecimal : ")
    
    if hexa ==("1" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9" or "a" or "b" or "c" or "d" or "e" or "f"):
        denary = int(hexa,16)
        print("Your Denary number is : ",denary)
        print("\n")
        print("===================================================")
        menu=input("Would You Like To Return To The Selection Menu?(Y,N) : ").upper()
        if menu == "Y".upper():
            main()
        elif menu == "N".upper():
            print("\n")
            print("==================================")
            print("You Denary number is: ")
            print(denary)
            print("Thank You For Your Time!")
    
    else:
        print("Not In Range")
        option6()
```

Comment: Use `if hexa.lower() in "123456789abcdef":` instead of so many `or`s

Comment: Learn how to debug Python in order to understand the program you have written.

Comment: What happened to `0` not being part of hexadecimal numbers?

Comment: You did not try your code, did you? You would get an exception.

Comment: sorry i missed the zero @peter M

Comment: whenever i tried the code it always said not in range no matter what value i would enter @Elis Byberi

Comment: @RishabSudhir Why you do not post that error in question? Post the full error.

Answer (score 2):

Open an interactive python shell (i.e. run 'python' in a terminal without arguments), and input `"1" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9" or "a" or "b" or "c" or "d" or "e" or "f"`.

What do you see?

```
>>> "1" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9" or "a" or "b" or "c" or "d" or "e" or "f"
'1'
```

Exactly. The expression `a or b` evaluates to `a` if `a` can be converted to `True`, and to `b` otherwise. Thus your `if` check reduces to `if hexa == "1":`

You should have written the longer `hexa == "1" or hexa == "3" or ...`. Or use the `in` keyword like `hexa in ["1", "3", "4", "5", ...]`. Or, since the righthand side is all single character strings, you can use `hexa in "134567..."` because a string is also iterable by character, and a character is a string itself.

---

If you want to parse any hexadecimal number recognized by `int()`, you can simply catch the `ValueError` exception:

```
hexa = input("Please Enter a Hexadecimal : ")
try:
    denary = int(hexa, 16)
    print("Your Denary number is : ",denary)
    ...
except ValueError:
    print("Not In Range")
    option6()
```

Comment: sorry im not very experianced in python yet

Comment: when you call `int(hexa,16)` it will try to parse `hexa` as a base-16 number. if it is not a valid base-16 number, a `ValueError` exception will be raised. see more at [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) in the Python manual.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have coding with Python 3.x, I'm using Python 2.7, so my code as below show. it's work for me!

```
# Python2.x --> raw_input
# Python3.x --> input

def option6():
    print("\n")
    print("----------------HEXADECIMAL-DENARY-----------------")
    #converts the entered hexadecimal (in base 16) into a integer using the int function
    hexa = str(raw_input("Please Enter a Hexadecimal : "))
    #hexa = str(input("Please Enter a Hexadecimal : ")) 

    if hexa in ('1', '3', '4', '5','6', 'a', 'b','c','d','e', 'f'):
        denary = int(hexa,16)
        print("Your Denary number is : ",denary)
        print("\n")
        print("===================================================")
        menu= raw_input("Would You Like To Return To The Selection Menu? (Y/N) :")  or 'Y' # default yes
        #menu= input("Would You Like To Return To The Selection Menu? (Y/N) :")  or 'Y' # default yes
        print 'menu-->', menu
        if menu == "Y":
            return

        elif menu == "N":
            print("\n")
            print("==================================")
            print("You Denary number is: ")
            print(denary)
            print("Thank You For Your Time!")

    else:
        print("Not In Range")
        option6()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    option6()
```

Comment: what do you mean by raw input(is that a function?) sorry i just started python

Comment: @RishabSudhir check out your python version at first， and then choice input build in function